# had the dinner there

Tags: definite-article, idiomatic-language

*It was my son's birthday yesterday. My ex-wife's new boyfriend owns a restaurant, so they had **the** dinner there.*

Does this sound completely natural? In particular my use of the definite article before "dinner"?

Comment: We are not supposed to provide editing services here. That said, if there had been a discussion about **that dinner** in the conversation, **the dinner** is fine. If not, it isn't.

Comment: The usual expression is *have dinner*, without the article. It refers to the meal they ate yesterday. 

However, you can say *they had a dinner*. It means they held a celebration, a special event. The indefinite article makes sense because you introduce it.

Comment: "a dinner" would not work here. We only use the indefinite article before a meal if it's qualified: "a light dinner", "an early breakfast". Either "dinner" or "the dinner"— and the latter makes it all the more clear that it's the one associated with the birthday party.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Others would disagree with you   https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+dinner%2Chave+the+dinner&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20dinner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20the%20dinner%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @RonaldSole Ah, I suppose one could say (as I see in some of those citations) "a dinner" as in "a dinner event". Some of [them](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22have%20a%20dinner%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2009,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en) sound pretty bizarre to my North American English ears, though. I certainly would question it in the sentence the OP given. (Also, I wouldn't expect "have the dinner" to occur very frequently in books.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine. We often use that phrasing in similar contexts.

Of course, as Lambie wrote, it presupposes that you usually have a (special) birthday dinner fpr members of your family, or that you've discussed this dinner earlier in the conversation.

Outside the context of an event such as a birthday or Christmas, you just say "have dinner" (and similarly for the other meals).

Answer (score 0):

please check page 146 of the book ''English Grammar in Use, 5th Edition'' by R. Murphy. You don't have to use ''the'' when you say ''We had lunch in an expensive restaurant'' or ''I had boiled eggs for breakfast.'' but you should use ''a/an'' when you say ''We had a great dinner'' or ''What a wonderful breakfast it was!''

Comment: In general you should not use "the", but when you connect it to an event that typically involves a meal, it's very common. For example: "My parents separated two weeks before Christmas. We couldn't decide where to have the dinner, so we decided to go to a restaurant." It's similar to saying "the reception" when talking about a wedding; since it's assumed that every wedding has a reception, one refers to said (definite) reception using "the".